# What server performance issues do low-bandwidh clients cause?

Tags: performance, distribution

I have a project to distribute large files to clients, some of which certainly will have low bandwidth (ISDN or DSL class).

The system is interactive, with clients pulling data from the server.

Just curious what kind of performance issues I can expect will be imposed by these lower bandwidth connections when compared to a client with a fatter pipe.

TIA

jeff

Answer (score 0):

Your max connections could go too high depending on your user population.

If you expect a ton of clients then adjust the web server connections to support it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have thousands and thousands of clients, you will have lots of memory used in OS socket buffers.